# Custom element inheritance

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I would seem that the lifecycle callbacks fire but I cannot access the mother class properties.

For exemple I have this custom element :

```
var Game = document.registerElement('x-game', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
        cards: {
            value: [],
            writable : true,
            enumerable : true,
        },
        createdCallback: {
            value: function () {
                this.cards = deck();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

With deck() a function to populate my array.

and I want to create an another element inheriting the former :

```
var Golf = document.registerElement('x-golf', {
    prototype: Object.create(Game.prototype, {
        columns: {
            value: []
        },
        waste: {
            value: new Waste
        },
        talon: {
            value: new Talon
        },
        createdCallback: {
            value: function () {    
                Game.prototype.createdCallback.apply();
                this.initialize();
            }
        },
        initialize: {
            value : function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                var column = new Column;
                for (var r = 0; r < 5; r++){
                    column.cards[r] = this.cards.pop();
                }
                this.columns[i] = column;
            }
            this.waste.cards.push(this.cards.pop());
            for (var j = 0; j < this.cards.length; j++){
                var card = this.cards.pop();
                card.side = 'verso';
                this.talon.cards[j] = card;
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Normally with `Game.prototype.createdCallback.apply();` the cards property on a new x-golf element shoud be populated however it is not. The value of the card property on the console is still an empty array, the default value for it.

So How to ensure that the card property will be correctly populated be the call of the superclass createdCallback ?

Comment: This is Polymer / webcomponents, right? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: I assume Polymer? I mean it's [specced](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#extensions-to-document-interface-to-register) in draft but I don't think any browser does this yet on its own.

Comment: @Benjamin: Apparently there is also http://www.x-tags.org/, as I just found out about.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, I wasn't aware of that :) Looks like it has [over 500 stars on GH](https://github.com/x-tag/core) too. Not the 5500 of Polymer but still not too shabby.

Comment: Well, I would like to use vanilla js that why I did not tag it with polymer. I use their Custom element polyfill though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum to make things clear: Polymer !== Web Components. Web Components is its own native thing. Polymer is just a thin layer on top of that. And so is X-Tag. But X-Tag only uses Custom Elements APIs. You can read about that here:http://pascalprecht.github.io/2014/07/21/polymer-vs-x-tag-here-is-the-difference/

Comment: I'm aware of that :) Thanks for clarifying for other people to read though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a target for the `.apply()` call:

```
Game.prototype.createdCallback.apply(this);
```

Working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fufewoju/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. However, should'nt the call to the createdCallback be automatic in case of inheritance?